# Perform a conditional lookup, only when the localfield exists?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection, which contains two types of documents. Based on the type of document I want to perform lookups aggregation.

Action is a collection, which contains both conversations and message type of actions. I want to perform a lookup for conversation and messages differently based on the fields present in MongoDB.

The action document for conversation type is as follows

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("592bdeaf45c7201421793871"), 
    "actionType" : "conversation", 
    "created" : NumberInt(1496047280), 
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("590c53a85fba594a59fe3d0f"), 
        ObjectId("590c50175df715499129e41b")
    ], 
    "conversationId" : ObjectId("592bdeaf45c7201421793870"), 
    "missionId" : ObjectId("590c50fa5df715499129e41c")
}
```

Action document for message

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("592bdeaf45c7201421793871"), 
    "actionType" : "message", 
    "created" : NumberInt(1496047280), 
    "messageId" : ObjectId("592bdeaf45c7201421793870")
}
```

I want actions after a particular time and want to perform lookups to get the conversation and message data from their object Ids.

I tried this

```
let matchQuery = {
          users : new ObjectId(userId),
          created:
            {
              $gt : createdTime
            }};

       let aggregation = [
          {
            $match : matchQuery
          },
          {$cond : 
            {if:
              {
                $users:{
                  $exists:true
                }
            }, 
          then: {
            $unwind : "$users",
            $lookup: {
                 from : "users",
                 localfield:"$users",
                 foreignfield:"_id",
                 as:"userDetail"
                       },
            $group:{
                  "users" : { $push : "userDetail"}
                    }
                  }
              }
            },
            {$cond : 
            {if:
              {
                $conversationId:{
                  $exists:true
                }
            }, 
          then: {
           $lookup : {
                            from:"conversations",
                            localfield:"conversationId",
                            foreignfield:"_id",
                            as:"conversationDetail"
                          }
                  }
              }
            },
            {$cond : 
            {if:
              {
                $missionId:{
                  $exists:true
                }
            }, 
          then: {
           $lookup : {
                            from:"services_v2",
                            localfield:"missionId",
                            foreignfield:"_id",
                            as:"missionDetail"
                          }
                  }
              }
            },
            {$cond : 
            {if:
              {
                $messageId:{
                  $exists:true
                }
            }, 
          then: {
           $lookup : {
                            from:"messagev2",
                              localfield:"messageId",
                              foreignfield:"_id",
                              as:"messageDetail"
                          }
                  }
              }
            },
          {
            $project : {
              "_id" : 1,
              "actionType" : 1,
              "userDetail":1,
              "conversationDetail":1,
              "missionDetail":1,
              "messageDetail":1
}}
        ];

connection.collection('actions')
.aggregate(aggregation).toArray((err,result)=> {  
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
 })
};
```

Comment: I have tried switch, but it does not recognize the lookup or unwind expressions.

Comment: Show a sample of what you are talking about in your question. Use some real documents and show expected results. Use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44241188/edit) link on your question rather than adding to comments.

Comment: Updated it with code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this a little bit and you don't need a "conditional lookup", and it's probably best to demonstrate by example.

Take these documents in separate collections, first the conversation:

```js
> db.conversation.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592ccbf8fceb6b40e6489759"), "message" : "I'm here" }
```

Then the message collection:

```js
> db.message.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc0bfceb6b40e648975a"), "text" : "Something here" }
```

And then I have a master collection that has references to each of those documents in separate documents:

```js
> db.master.find()
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc73fceb6b40e648975b"),
  "a" : 1, 
  "conversation" : ObjectId("592ccbf8fceb6b40e6489759")
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc95fceb6b40e648975c"),
  "a" : 2,
  "message" : ObjectId("592ccc0bfceb6b40e648975a")
}
```

Now if I do a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operation ( which is somewhat analogous to a "left join" ):

```js
db.master.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "conversation",
    "localField": "conversation",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "conversation"
  }}
])
```

Then I get a result like this, which of course projects an empty array on the document that did not have a `"localField"` to match:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc73fceb6b40e648975b"),
    "a" : 1,
    "conversation" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("592ccbf8fceb6b40e6489759"),
            "message" : "I'm here"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc95fceb6b40e648975c"),
    "a" : 2,
    "message" : ObjectId("592ccc0bfceb6b40e648975a"),
    "conversation" : [ ]
}
```

If I now add to the pipeline a "second" [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operation to link to the message collection:

```js
db.master.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "conversation",
    "localField": "conversation",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "conversation"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "message",
    "localField": "message",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "message"
  }}
])
```

Then we see the similar effect where the document that does not have the property now has an empty array, but where the property did exist we now have the entry from the specific collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc73fceb6b40e648975b"),
    "a" : 1,
    "conversation" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("592ccbf8fceb6b40e6489759"),
            "message" : "I'm here"
        }
    ],
    "message" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc95fceb6b40e648975c"),
    "a" : 2,
    "message" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc0bfceb6b40e648975a"),
            "text" : "Something here"
        }
    ],
    "conversation" : [ ]
}
```

You can either leave this as it is ( which seems to be the desired final state of what you tried so far ) or now do other operations with it, such as combining into a single array:

```js
db.master.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "conversation",
    "localField": "conversation",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "conversation"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "message",
    "localField": "message",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "message"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "a": 1,
    "combined": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$conversation",
          "as": "el",
          "in": {
            "type": "conversation",
            "_id": "$$el._id",
            "message": "$$el.message"
          }
        }},
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$message",
          "as": "el",
          "in": {
            "type": "message",
            "_id": "$$el._id",
            "text": "$$el.text"
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Which outputs as:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc73fceb6b40e648975b"),
    "a" : 1,
    "combined" : [
        {
            "type" : "conversation",
            "_id" : ObjectId("592ccbf8fceb6b40e6489759"),
            "message" : "I'm here"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc95fceb6b40e648975c"),
    "a" : 2,
    "combined" : [
        {
            "type" : "message",
            "_id" : ObjectId("592ccc0bfceb6b40e648975a"),
            "text" : "Something here"
        }
    ]
}
```

The point being that [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) will quite intentionally simply leave behind an "empty arrray" if either the `"localField"` or `"foreignField"` expressions do not match any elements. This does not affect the document results returned other than adding the empty array property for the target.

Now you can "loose" documents using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), but that will also only happen if you omit the [`"preserveNullAndEmptyArrays"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#includearrayindex-and-preservenullandemptyarrays) option, which is there to deal with such occurrences.

But for general usage of a "discriminator" based [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), then simply use separate pipeline stage for each collection you want to "link" to.

Comment: You were right about me overthinking it. Also found mongo supports multiple array lookups, hence I do not need to unwind and group them again for users. Also because of a silly mistake of using "localfield" instead of "localField" :D . Thanks again :)

Comment: Is there any way I can keep them as objects and not make it an array ? I do not want to return empty fields either. Plus I want each detail to be nested under a field unlike how it is presented.

Comment: @HemantKumarGoyal If you have another question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It's the best way to explain your intentions and desired output anyway.

Comment: @HemantKumarGoyal Read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which will guide you. And especially [How do I get out of a question ban?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) in the linked help center article. But pleading to have an existing answer expanded into answering another question is not going to help your case. Follow the steps and suggestions there.