# how to perform conditionnally JOIN in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I would like to make Join on two collections on given fields according to condition,
for that i tried to make aggregation request with to lookups, the both lookups are performed according to a condition : the field exists or not.

Here is my code :

```
public void buildLookupStage(){

  LookupOperation lookup1 = LookupOperation.newLookup().
                            from("DRAW").
                            localField("ids").
                            foreignField("id").as("DRAWS");

   LookupOperation lookup2 = LookupOperation.
                             newLookup().from("DRAW").
                             localField("ids").foreignField("userId").
                             as("DRAWS");

   ConditionalOperators.Cond ifIdExists = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("id").exists(true).
                                 andOperator(Criteria.where("userId").exists(false))).
                                 then(lookUp1).otherwise("");

   ConditionalOperators.Cond ifUserIdExists = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("userId").
                                 exists(true)).then(lookUp2).otherwise("");

   Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
   Aggregation.replaceRoot().withValueOf(ifIdExists),
   Aggregation.replaceRoot().withValueOf(ifUserIdExists));

}
```

I did with spring data mongoDB, but i got an error : unRecognize expression $exists

i also tried to look this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241188/perform-a-conditional-lookup-only-when-the-localfield-exists) but it is not the same context, there, they perform 2 JOIN sequentially, but me i would like to perform the JOIN between 2 collections on different foreignField according to a given condition.
So is there a way to perform this ?